# A Question About Net Module For Handling Messages in the Back-end

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, real-time, node-mysql2

In Node.js, I designed my own custom protocol for handling messages using net module; however, I'm not sure whether this code saves the messages to the database real-time or not. That is, I want to learn if this code works real-time or not. Here's the entire code:

```
const net = require("net");
 const mysql = require("mysql2");

 const server = net.createServer(socket => {
    socket.on("data", data => {
          db.query("INSERT INTO messages (message) VALUES (?)", [data.toString()], (e, r) => {
        if (!e) {
            console.log("Saved the message successfully!");
        }

        else {
            throw e;
        }
      });
    });
});

 server.listen(3000, "127.0.0.1", () => {
    console.log("Connected to the server successfully!");
});

 const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    port: 3306,
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "message"
});

 db.connect(err => {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("Connected to the database successfully!");
    }

    else {
        throw err;
    }
});
```

**I couldn't be sure about whether this code is real-time or not. I want to save the messages to the database real-time, not asynchronously.**

Comment: That is not what [real-time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing) means.

Comment: Why do you care? What does it mean to you? What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: @Bergi, I'm currently developing a real-time messaging app. Therefore, I want to learn how this code works exactly.

Comment: [Fine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_communication). So again, what are your real-time guarantees?

Comment: "*I want to learn how this code works exactly*" - then read the docs of the libraries you are using (or even study their code). You'll find that both `net.createServer` and `db.query` use an asynchronous programming model. But this has nothing to do with whether your system will be able to meet your real-time demands or not.